# Implementing Lazy Enumerator in Crystal

Tags: lazy-evaluation, crystal-lang, enumerator

In Ruby to build a custom lazy enumerator, one can utilize `Enumerator` like this:

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |e|
  e << value = ".a"
  loop { e << value = value.next }
end

enum.next # => ".a"
enum.next # => ".b"
enum.next # => ".c"
enum.rewind
enum.next # => ".a"
```

What's the Crystal's idiomatic way to imitate such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit wordier... Look at `Iterator<T>`

```
class DotChar
  include Iterator(String)

  @current : String = ""

  def initialize
    @start = ".a"
    rewind
  end

  def next
    @current.tap { @current = @current.succ }
  end

  def rewind
    @current = @start
  end
end

e = DotChar.new
p e.next # => ".a"
p e.next # => ".b"
p e.next # => ".c"
e.rewind
p e.next # => ".a"
```

(Can't use `enum` as the identifier, as that's a keyword in Crystal.)

You can do it much simpler if you sacrifice rewind:

```
s = ".a"
e = Iterator.of { s.tap { s = s.succ } }
```

There may be in the future a way to do exactly as in Ruby, but it is a work in progress (that I hope wasn't abandoned yet, it seems to have stalled half a year ago). See [this issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6357) and [this pull request](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/6385) for more info.

Comment: The PR is mostly good. I think it's just waiting for a few concurrency features to arrive in stdlib that would make it possible to run this with correct error propagation. Until then, this is probably to brittle to be merged.